# How to pass functions defined in a class as arguments to functions?

Tags: c++

getMessage method extracts the first letter in each word of input string.

Example:
 input = "Find the      first  letters of this Sentence"

output = FtflotS

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <vector>
        #include <algorithm>
        #include <cctype>
        using namespace std;
        class HiddenMessage {
        public:
          bool space (char c) {
            return isspace(c);
          }
          bool not_space (char c) {
            return !isspace (c);
          }
          string getMessage(string text) {
            string ret;
            typedef string::const_iterator iter;
            iter  i, j;
            i = text.begin();
            while (i != text.end()) {
              i = find_if (i, text.end(), not_space); // error here
              j = find_if (i, text.end(), space); // error here
              if (i != text.end()) {
                  ret += *i;
              }
              i = j;
            }
            return ret;
          }
        };

        //compiler error:
        //error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

I tried making definitions of space and not_space static and it did
not work.

getMessage is called from the main below:

```
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
      if (argc == 1) 
        {
          cout << "Testing HiddenMessage (250.0 points)" << endl << endl;
          for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
              ostringstream s; s << argv[0] << " " << i;
              int exitCode = system(s.str().c_str());
              if (exitCode)
                cout << "#" << i << ": Runtime Error" << endl;
            }
          int T = time(NULL)-1456061889;
          double PT = T/60.0, TT = 75.0;
          cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
          cout.precision(2);
          cout << endl;
          cout << "Time  : " << T/60 << " minutes " << T%60 << " secs" << endl;
          cout << "Score : " << 250.0*(.3+(.7*TT*TT)/(10.0*PT*PT+TT*TT)) << " points" << endl;
        }
      else
        {
          int _tc; istringstream(argv[1]) >> _tc;
          HiddenMessage _obj;
          string _expected, _received;
          time_t _start = clock();
          switch (_tc)
            {
            case 0:
              {
                string text = "compete online design event rating";
                _expected = "coder";
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
              }
            case 1:
              {
                string text = "  c    o d     e      r    ";
                _expected = "coder";
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
              }
            case 2:
              {
                string text = "round  elimination during  onsite  contest";
                _expected = "redoc";
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
              }
            case 3:
              {
                string text = " ";
                _expected = "";
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
              }
              /*case 4:
                {
                string text = ;
                _expected = ;
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
                }*/
              /*case 5:
                {
                string text = ;
                _expected = ;
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
                }*/
              /*case 6:
                {
                string text = ;
                _expected = ;
                _received = _obj.getMessage(text); break;
                }*/
            default: return 0;
            }
          cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
          cout.precision(2);
          double _elapsed = (double)(clock()-_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
          if (_received == _expected)
            cout << "#" << _tc << ": Passed (" << _elapsed << " secs)" << endl;
          else
            {
              cout << "#" << _tc << ": Failed (" << _elapsed << " secs)" << endl;
              cout << "           Expected: " << "\"" << _expected << "\"" << endl;
              cout << "           Received: " << "\"" << _received << "\"" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling `getMessage` in your `main()` or application entry point?

Comment: 1: It's called member functions, not methods. 2: There seems to be absolutely no need for these to be part of any class. Make all of them free functions. Or, if you want to keep them inside the class for whatever reason, make them static.

Comment: Making space and not_space static gives following 

error: no matching function for call to 'find_if(iter&, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, bool (&)(char))'

@JonathanOgden  I am calling getMessage in my main()

Comment: @AnoopGR Please add such information to your question to save everybodies time.

Comment: Try `text.cend()` to get a constant iterator.

Comment: Changing const_iterator  to iterator in typedef solved the problem. Thank you Daniel for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first, is you are supplying non-static class member functions (`space` and `not_space`) to `find_if` which expects a function object or pointer. So, declare them `static` if you want them to remain your class, or make them global by placing them outside the class.

The second, your string `text` parameter is non-const, but, you are working with a `const` interator type. `begin()` and `end()` calls will return const or non-const iterator depending on the calling object (`text` in this case) and whether or not it is const qualified. So, declare your `text` parameter as `const`.

Comment: note: `cbegin()` and `cend()` work in only C++11 and above

Comment: Apologies, I did not check what cpp standard you were working with. For earlier standards, you've already got the solution.

Comment: @AnoopGR revised my answer to better explain the situation and solution for you.

Comment: @JonathanOgden Thank you very much